# TSQL & VBA - Output / Return Value?

Tags: sql-server, vba, t-sql, stored-procedures

I seem to be having difficulty getting a return value from my SP into VBA.

I have issued a RETURN in my T-SQL which is fine, but I can't seem to work out how to get the value in the VBA?

```
Dim qd As QueryDef
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim vRate As Integer
vRate = 3
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qd = db.QueryDefs("spCC_UpdateRAG")

' inital rating
qd.SQL = "EXEC spCC_UpdateRAG @Col = 'Rating', @RAG = " & Nz(vRate, "NULL") & ", @Case_ID = 36"
qd.Execute
```

This works fine other than I can't seem to get the return value?

So I thought I would try with OUPUT params instead, but SQL moans if you don't assign them a value, which makes no sense as they are output not input params?

So I tried this in my T-SQL...

```
-- return failure (false)   
SET @Result = 0

SELECT @Result
```

but that gives me a result set return which I don't want and a column with no name, so if I have to do this..

```
-- return failure (false)   
SET @Result = 0

SELECT @Result AS Result
```

What's the point? I might as well do...

```
SELECT 0 AS Result
```

And either way I'm getting back a recordset and I don't want one, I just want to return a bit (true/false)

Was the SP successful or not, how do I do this and get the value in my VBA code?

Your input is appreciated.
1DMF

Comment: See how the argument `adParamReturnValue` was used in the `CreateParameter` method of the `ADODB.Command` object in [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12407906/772086).

Comment: ? I'm not using ADODB, are you saying it isn't possible using what I have been told by the access community to use for all my DB activities -> DAO.

Comment: Well that's not a question for which I can give a one sentence answer. The short answer is in the case of DAO vs ADODB "Always use X" is an oversimplification. You can almost always *get away with* standing by one option and usually won't notice any real difference. I suggest you do some googling.

Comment: Regarding "I have been told by the access community to use [DAO] for all my DB activities", DAO is best for the Jet/ACE database engine. ADODB allows you to tap into SQL Server directly, so I recommend it in this situation, which agrees with the [general consensus](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3025976/772086).

Comment: Thanks Mike, I'll look into it, though I would point out that I use nothing but MS SQL via linked tables or SP's and pass-through queries with DAO and have done for many years, hence wondering why people claim for SQL you need ADODB, when I know you don't. It's always difficult to sift though a sea of peoples opinions to get to the truth and what is actually needed to resolve the problem.

Comment: One good reason to use ADODB: It has the same code for different types of databases (including MS Access). DAO _only_ works against MS Access. If you ever want to use a server based database such as SQL Server its worth learning ADO

Comment: What are you talking about?, this application is SQL 2008R2 backend with VBA front end and has been ever since SQL 2005. Anyone reading this please understand DAO works with MS SQL and anyone who says differently is wrong! 

Here is another DAO -> SLQ Server satisfied customer and as M$ apparently are recommending DAO over ADO , I'm not sure why people keep saying DAO doesn't work with MS SQL, I guess they have never tried : http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=250033

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I went for the following solution as I couldn't seem to get either a return value or a parameter collection back in my VBA code. (perhaps a limitation of a pass-through query with DAO?)

The SP simply returns a recordset, 1 row / 1 column (Result = 0|1)

Then in the VBA

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim qd AS QueryDef
Dim bOK As Boolean

Set qd = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("my_pass_through_query")
qd.SQL = "EXEC my_SP @arg1 = 'value1', @arg2 = value2"
Set rs = qd.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot)
bOK = rs.Fields("Result")

Set rs = Nothing
Set qd = Nothing
```

It's a little convoluted for what I was trying to achieve but it works.